# How to find out the value of $n$ in the given expression.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

How can I find out the given expressions value of n? $$\frac{a+b}{2}=\frac{a^n+b^n}{a^{n-1}+b^{n-1}}$$
I tried multiplying both sides by denominator, but it didn't work. Also, observing tells me one value of $n$ can be $1$.

Comment: If $n$ is an odd positive integer, then $(a+b)$ is a factor of $(a^n+b^n)$

Comment: @aibohphobia I believe it will still factor if $n$ is an even integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$0=a^n+b^n-a^{n-1}b-ab^{n-1}=a(a^{n-1}-b^{n-1})-b(a^{n-1}-b^{n-1})=(a^{n-1}-b^{n-1})(a-b)$$

Comment: In terms of $n$, I think this means the only observed solution is also the only solution.

Comment: @abiessu, If $a=b,$ this is an identity. Else $$\left(\dfrac ab\right)^{n-1}=1$$   If $a/b=-1, n-1$ is even.  Else $n-1=0$